# How do I get an array of parse objects in android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

When extending a parse object how do I get an array of parse Objects? I am trying to do it in the extension of my parseObject. Here is some example code. How would I get my getAplicants() method to return an arrayList of parseUsers

```
@ParseClassName("Listing")
public class Listing extends ParseObject {
    public static final String APLICANTS_KEY = "aplicants";

    //APLICANTS
    public ArrayList<ParseUser> getAplicants(){
        return //arrayList of parseUsers
    }
}
```